# multiple Play Store Accounts sharing same android signing key

Tags: android, google-play, apk, signing

as the title says, can a signed android apk be published/signed by multiple google play accounts?

we have a possible new requirement where we will have to remove the existing play account and create a new one but we are keeping the same signed keys for our apps and do not want to upload a whole new app with new signing key.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add additional users to your applications and give them whatever permissions you feel are appropriate. To do so, follow the [Add Developer account users & manage permissions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691?hl=en) guide.

However, it sounds like you don't really just want to add additional users. It sounds like you want to do a full transfer of the application to a new account. In that case, you will want to follow the [Transfer apps to a different developer account](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en) guide.