# Is it possible to sign different apps in different Google Play accounts with the same key?

Tags: android, security, google-play, key

Context: Google Play /Android Marketplace

I searched and so far I did not find a specific answer, I'd like to know if it is possible to sign an APK with a key (private) and then use the same key for a completely different account and app? If this is done like this will this be recognized as the same owner?

There are [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455947/multiple-play-store-accounts-sharing-same-android-signing-key), but in my case I this is about 2 different apps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this should be possible. I have used the same keystore file for 2 different applications in 2 different accounts. One was personal and other was organization account.

> If this is done like this will this be recognized as the same owner?

What do you mean by this? Did not understand this.

Comment: I mean for the end user, will they see this 2 different apps as the same source just because they were signed using the same key?

Comment: by source = authoring identity

Comment: no they won't. It will show based on the app developer account.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is recognize in the playstore with package name so it wont be any issue if you use the same keystore or different for multiple apps. playstore will accept your app if the package name different.